# Boolean condition affected by inputs

Tags: boolean, symbolic-math

I was testing what happens when I pass random values to an arbitrary boolean condition in Python. I ran a loop 10 times and declared each time a random choice of True or False to A and B. I then saw if the condition returned True or False and outputted the values of A and B.

```
for i in range(10):
    A = random.choice([True, False])
    B = random.choice([True, False])

    if (A and (A or B)) == True:
        print("Pass:")
        print("A: {} B: {}".format(A, B))
    else:
        print("Fail:")
        print("A: {} B: {}".format(A, B))
```

**Outputs:**

```
Pass:              Fail:               Pass:                Pass:
A: True B: True    A: False B: True    A: True B: False     A: True B: False 
Pass:              Pass:               Pass:
A: True B: True    A: True B: False    A: True B: True 
Pass:              Pass:               Fail:
A: True B: True    A: True B: True     A: False B: False
```

The boolean condition I chose was sort of randomly written (meaning no particular reason for that one), but I found a sort of pattern in the outputs.

The value of B in all the `Passes` was different (same for the `Fails`), but the value of A was always True in the `Passes` and False in the `Fails`. Remember that a `Pass` is the result of the condition being True, hence it seems the condition happens to return a boolean value which is the same as the input A.

Since I found this particular condition odd, I ran another test. This time I checked if this boolean expression always gave the same as the initial input of A. I also ran it 20 times to get more random values for the inputs.

```
for i in range(20):
    A = random.choice([True, False])
    B = random.choice([True, False])
    if (A and (A or B)) == A:
        print("Pass")
    else:
        print("Fail")
```

**Output:**

```
Pass
Pass
Pass
. . .
Pass
Pass
Pass
```

I have simplified the output, but when I ran the code, it gave all 20 passes and the same when the code was run a few times.

My question is why does this condition, I guess "simplify", to just the input A? And can boolean expressions be "simplified" (as in this situation the whole expression renders pointless if the result is always just A) in order to shorten conditions?

Answer (score 1):

This is a trivial result in symbolic logic.

If `A` is true, then your expression evaluates as follows:

```
True and (True or B)
True or B
True
```

Answer (score 1):

This field of mathematics is called Boolean algebra. Your specific example is the Absorption Law, eg form 10a or "X • (X + Y) = X" here:

https://www.mi.mun.ca/users/cchaulk/misc/boolean.htm

(In Boolean algebra, "and" is sometimes written as • and "or" is sometimes written as +. This makes analogies to integer algebra more obvious, eg X + 0 = X and X • 0 = 0.)

Your larger question of "can boolean expressions be simplified" depends on the expression! Often they can, but certain forms are fully simplified. A full discussion is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow - there are various web resources or online classes. It's not particularly difficult but it's a bigger subject than one answer can cover.